# Is there any other way to implement RichTextField in a django blog

Tags: python, html, django, ckeditor

I'm working on my blog web using django. In my models.py I implemented `RichtextField` instead of the normal `CharField` or `Textfield` or others. I already imported it like this `from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField` after installing `'ckeditor'` in '**INSTALLED_APPS** in my projects settings.py.

Everything is working just Fine!

But there is problem!

The problem i'm facing is, I don't get to see the result of whatever I type in in my Django admin site using the RichTextField except plain text and some HTML tags in my localhost page.

What I mean is:

Supposing in my text-typing, I have something like this *'This is a bright new day...'*, and I want to bold *'bright'* like this- ***'bright'***. I get to see it working perfectly in my django admin site. But when I refresh to my localhost page to where the text-typing is displayed, I get to see some weird HTML tag like this *<b 'bright' /b>* instead of ***'bright'***. And it did the same thing when I used summernotes.

So, please I will like to know why it's going that direction instead of the direction I want.

Secondly, the possibly solution to help me make move in the direction I want.

This same problem cut across to when I want implement codes, italics, headers, etc. in my whatever text I wish to change to those form.

Comment: In your template you should add filter `safe` like that  `{{ blog.description | safe}}`

Comment: @mirodil thanks for this. It slipped my mind. It's working perfectly well now